# extracting sub array of array

Tags: python, arrays

Hi my question is in regards to the J.F. Sebastian code and discussion below.
I am trying to print a sub array of an array.  The code is below and my update is on the bottom. (It gives error messages)[creating a spiral array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834505/creating-a-spiral-array-in-python)

I want to create a sub array based on a chosen entry in this array. if we choose the 04 entry,

```
subarray[x][y] == 04
subarray[x][y] == TheSpiral[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2]

print_matrix(TheSpiral)  
print_matrix(subarray)
```

However I get an error message due to not properly defining subarray.  I was expecting the print_matrix(subarray) to yield

```
06 01 02
05 04 03
16 15 14
```

which is why I used #TheSpiral[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2].  Thanks for the help.

Comment: **`I get error messages`** is hardly a good description of the problem. What are your error messages? Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the second slice doesn't do what you think it does

- it's a syntax error with standard list and you should use `[][]`, however ...
- the second indices is not slicing the individual sub arrays, a slice returns the list of lists which the second slice would also operate on

You can fix it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> i, j = 3, 2
>>> subarray = [row[j-1:j+2] for row in TheSpiral[i-1:i+2]]
>>> print_matrix(subarray)
06 01 02
05 04 03
16 15 14
```

Alternatively you can use `numpy` (which maybe overkill!!!) and use your original syntax:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> subarray = np.array(TheSpiral)[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]
>>> print_matrix(subarray)
06 01 02
05 04 03
16 15 14
```

To calculate the spiral coordinates:

```
def spiral_coord(n):
    k = int((n**0.5) // 2)
    t = 2*k
    m = (t+1)**2
    for fn in (lambda: (-k, k-(m-n)), lambda: (-k+(m-n), -k), lambda: (k, -k+(m-n))):
        if n >= m-t:
            return fn()
        m -= t
    return k-(m-n-t), k

>>> mid = (5-1)//2
>>> i, j = map(lambda x: x+mid, spiral_coord(9))
>>> subarray = np.array(TheSpiral)[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]
>>> print_matrix(subarray)
23 24 25
08 09 10
01 02 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is a syntactical error in your subarray code. As the method "spiral" returns a 2D array(TheSpiral in your case), the way of accessing the elements of the 2D array must be

```
TheSpiral[i][j]
```

not

```
TheSpiral[i,j]
```