# python3 - create list of strings elliptically

Tags: python-3.x

EDIT: I do not want your code! just help me think of a nice way to do it :)

I have a string with 25 characters:
ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

and I want to create a matrix5*5 given a position and a direction,
position can be one of the corners and direction can be clock or counter clock.

so if I gave this arguments:
create((0,0), clock)

I want to recive:
["ABCDE", "QRSTF", "PYZUG", "OXWVH", "NMLKI"]

and I could then print it and recieve:

A B C D E

Q R S T F

P Y Z U G

O X W V H

N M L K I

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to write your assignment for you.  Might I suggest that people here might be more helpful if you attempted it, posted your code, then asked specific questions about something not working correctly.

Comment: what is your concern any specific issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834505/creating-a-spiral-array-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706690/how-do-i-make-make-spiral-in-python can possibly be adapted. There are many more such spiral questions.

Comment: @Gerrat I have already coded this and it is working but I kinda brute forced it, as i know that the matrix is always 5*5 i have inserted the characters one by one depending on the position and direction. this works for me, but i would like to make this smarter.. I just cant think of anything.. I already tried something with this sequence (5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1) wich is the number of inputs to the list every time i change direction, but it is dumb asswel..

Comment: @A-B-B thanks! i guess i didnt search enough xD

Comment: If you figured out (5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1), then you should see a pattern ;)